# Executing and External Powershell Command from Ruby

Tags: ruby, powershell

I am trying to execute a Powershell command from ruby to capture the results and do some other processing.

```
var = `powershell Invoke-Command -computername myserver {Get-Eventlog application -newest 200 |      where {$_.Message -match "Found 0 files to refresh"}}`
puts var
```

Since the $_ variable is shared between the PS and Ruby i do get the following:

INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

Any ideas on how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

`$_.Message` is a Ruby global var?

```
var = `powershell Invoke-Command -computername myserver {Get-Eventlog application -newest 200 |      where {#{$_.Message} -match "Found 0 files to refresh"}}`
```

Comment: No, $_.Message is a Powershell variable but ruby thinks is a file handle :S